# generate pdf from html through IronPdf

Tags: .net

renderer is not recognized by program
using IronPdf;

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GeneratePdf()
{
    var htmlString = "<html><body><h1>Hello World!</h1></body></html>";

    var htmlToPdf = new HtmlToPdf();
    htmlToPdf.PrintOptions.PaperSize = PdfPrintOptions.PdfPaperSize.A4;
    htmlToPdf.PrintOptions.CssMediaType = PdfPrintOptions.PdfCssMediaType.Print;

    var pdf = await renderer.RenderHtmlAsPdfAsync(htmlString);

    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    pdf.SaveAs(stream);
    stream.Position = 0;

    return File(stream, "application/pdf", "example.pdf");
}
```

i want to generate pdf from html in dot net framework by using IronPdf package

Comment: what is the error here ?

Comment: @thunderkill renderer is not recognized

Comment: no screenshot no nothing, it could be the application pool that is blocking it if you are hosting this API if not clear project from cash . use this command for this `dotnet nuget locals --clear all`